# Use FFmpeg for continuous streaming from other source

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

We have an app that pipes its output, and its output is compress H264 data. The source of the data is from a 3d engine running in same app.

We can easily pipe the output in FFmpeg to save as *mp4* or even *m3u8*.

It's also possible to turn FFmpeg as a server to feed video files.

So our objective is to have FFmpeg read that data, convert into into *mp4* or *m3u8* internally and then stream so that it can be read in the web browser.

We don't care about be able to replay some file, go back in time or whatever, we just care about the current value.

Is there a way to do that? Or a similar solution that would allow some close to that.

Thanks

I guess, if it's possible, it's like wanting to stream your personal webcam into the web browser. Then you could connect to that and see what is happening at home or wherever your webcam is.

Comment: Just serve the m3u8 using standard http.

Comment: And how do I do that? Do I have to create files on disk for that? Or is m3u8 able to describe an infinite amount of TS files?

Comment: You should take a look at the m3u8 file (it updates as the video gets longer). You should probably also google HLS and learn a little about how it works. As far as setting up a http server, there are many resources online, or you can check out serverfault.con

Comment: So m3u8 can be dynamic then, that makes it a better solution. Currently reading about HLS. Already look into HLS.js for the client side.

Comment: @szatmary so.. you guys have found out a solution....? I'm lost here

Comment: @MiDaa A solution to what?